# Using nodeclipse with docker instead of local nodejs installation

Tags: eclipse, docker, nodeclipse

currently I'm evaluating, how to setup my web development infrastructure using docker.

I would like to use eclipse with [nodeclipse](http://www.nodeclipse.org/), but I don't want to install nodejs locally. Additionally I don't want to use [Eclipse Che](https://www.eclipse.org/che/).

So my question is, if it is possible to configure eclipse that I use a docker-container including nodejs?

The biggest challange currently is, that without nodejs I get error messages in my typescript code, that my imported packages can't be found.

Thank you for your help :)